# How to make lightgallery enter full screen mode with code?

Tags: javascript, photo-gallery, lightgallery

I want to make lightGallery ( https://github.com/sachinchoolur/lightGallery.git ) automatic enter full screen mode with a function call. 
But I can't find the way to make it work. 
Please help me.

Here is my code

```js
$("#preview").lightGallery({
    fullScreen: true
});

// TODO: I want automatic enter full screen mode by code here ( same with click on thumbnail image )
console.log('I want automatic enter full screen mode here');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightgallery/1.6.12/css/lightgallery.min.css" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightgallery/1.6.12/js/lightgallery-all.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lg-fullscreen/1.1.0/lg-fullscreen.min.js"></script>

<div id="preview">
  <a href="https://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightgallery.js/static/img/1.jpg">
    <img src="https://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightgallery.js/static/img/thumb-1.jpg">
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want that when you click on the image it takes the entire `width` of the screen? (a.k.a you want the image to fit screen?)

Comment: @ManuelAbascal, I want automatic show full screen mode after load page, or after load data with api or ( when user click on a button or something like that, not only click on image thumbnail ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the image to open automatically on page load, you can accomplish it by adding an `id` attribute to the `img` element & a `click` event to it like so:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="preview">
  <a href="https://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightgallery.js/static/img/1.jpg">
    <img id="gallery" src="https://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightgallery.js/static/img/thumb-1.jpg">
  </a>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$("#preview").lightGallery({
    fullScreen: true
});

$('#gallery').click()
```

You can check this [working code sample](https://jsfiddle.net/m97zutbL/).